# How to refresh layers independently?

Tags: api, c++, qgis-2, performance

I'm writing a C++ application using QGIS API and I would like to improve the performance.

I want to render 5 layers:

- one raster layer using gdal to load Bing/Google Map tiles
- 4 custom QgsMapLayer (using plugin layer type) to draw different lines/polygons/points in WGS84.

For now, each of these layer is added to the MapCanvas, using:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(customLayer);
QList <QgsMapCanvasLayer> myLayerSet;
myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(cutomLayer,TRUE));
setLayerSet(myLayerSet);
```

On the canvas, I can have map tools, like panning, zoom in/out.
I use custom layers because I want to easily decorate lines and polygons, using QPainter.
This works, and I'm able to display what i want, where i want (using coordinate transforms from WGS84 to pseudo mercator).

My problem is: **one of my custom layers draws a GPS point with some circles around it.
This layer is refreshed every second.**  To refresh my layer, I use the `canvas->refresh()`, but that refreshes all other layers as well, and by consequence, the GDAL layer. This takes a lot of time and it's not necessary.

I have read some posts here mentioning the use of `layer->setImageCache()`, or by sub-classing QgsMapCanvasItem. Unfortunately, none of theses solutions works as I expect. `setImageCache` apparently doesn't work at all, or I don't know how to use it properly.

Sub-classing QgsMapCanvasItem allows me to implement the layers that need frequent refresh, and refresh them without refresh Raster Layer but:

1. when panning the map, drawn objects don't follow the map (as a rubberBand can).
2. when i use zoom in/out, the selection rectangle erase what was drawn on my canvasItem, without triggering a redraw.

I don't see how to do that, even if this subject seems relatively common.

Am i on the right way or is there a better way?

**EDIT :**

thanks to Nathan, my problem is resolved, and i confirm that custom QgsMapCanvasItem is the solution to independently refresh some layers.
just keep in mind to use toCanvasCoordinates(), and implement boundingRect() properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `QgsMapCanvasItem` is the way to go here as you will not have to refresh the canvas.  You just have to make sure your implementation is correct.

Here is a basic example (taken from https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam/blob/master/src/roam/gps_action.py)

```
class GPSMarker(QgsMapCanvasItem):
        def __init__(self, canvas):
            QgsMapCanvasItem.__init__(self, canvas)
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.size = 24
            self.map_pos = QgsPoint(0.0, 0.0)
            self.svgrender = QSvgRenderer(":/icons/gps_marker")

        def setSize(self, size):
            self.size = size

        def paint(self, painter, xxx, xxx2):
            self.setPos(self.toCanvasCoordinates(self.map_pos))

            halfSize = self.size / 2.0
            self.svgrender.render(painter, QRectF(0 - halfSize, 0 - halfSize, self.size, self.size ) )

        def boundingRect(self):
            halfSize = self.size / 2.0
            return QRectF(-halfSize, -halfSize, 2.0 * halfSize, 2.0 * halfSize)

        def setCenter(self, map_pos):
            self.map_pos = map_pos
            self.setPos(self.toCanvasCoordinates(self.map_pos))

        def updatePosition(self):
            self.setCenter(self.map_pos)
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, it's works.

regarding that drawn object did not follow the map, when panning, it was due to a missed call to "toCanvasCoordinates".

regarding my second point, the erased objects where due to a missed implementation of boudingRect() Method.

the only problem i have now, is "How can i call toCanvasCoordinates directly on a custom QgsMapLayer" but i can move forward.