# How to write a custom canvas item for SVG marker by subclassing QgsMapCanvasItem in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, api, c++, svg, pyqt

I want to subclass QgsMapCanvasItem for SVG marker in QGIS, I looked up a similar topic in stackexchange and QGIS mailing list, I found that [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81465/how-to-refresh-layers-independently/81470#81470) is similar to mine, I did exactly what @Nathan W did. But when I instantiated custom canvas item, the app broke down to a break point. It says:

> "This may be due to a corruption of the heap..", see more in error.jpg.

[image: error.jpg].

I don't know why, can anyone help me out of it?

Here is my code:

```
//main.cpp
int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);

QgsMapCanvas * mypMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas();
mypMapCanvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
mypMapCanvas->setCanvasColor(Qt::white);
mypMapCanvas->freeze(false);
mypMapCanvas->setVisible(true);
mypMapCanvas->refresh();

QString fileName = "D:\\qgis\\svg\\symbol\\poi_tower_communications.svg";
TFMapCanvasSvgItem mTFSvgItem(mypMapCanvas, fileName);
mTFSvgItem.setPos(0, 0);

return app.exec();
}

//TFMapCanvasSvgItem.h --custom canvas item named TFMapCanvasSvgItem
class TFMapCanvasSvgItem: public QgsMapCanvasItem
{
public:
    TFMapCanvasSvgItem(QgsMapCanvas* canvas, QString fileName = "");
    ~TFMapCanvasSvgItem();

    void paint(QPainter* painter);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void setFilePath(const QString& file);
    QString filePath() const {return mFilePath;}

private:
    QSvgRenderer mSvgRenderer;
    QString mFilePath;
};

//TFMapCanvasSvgItem.cpp
TFMapCanvasSvgItem::TFMapCanvasSvgItem(QgsMapCanvas* canvas, QString fileName): QgsMapCanvasItem(canvas), mSvgRenderer(fileName)
{
}

TFMapCanvasSvgItem::~TFMapCanvasSvgItem()
{
}

void TFMapCanvasSvgItem::paint(QPainter* painter)
{
if (!painter)
{
    return;
}

QRectF viewBox = mSvgRenderer.viewBoxF();
if (viewBox.isValid())
{
    setPos(this->toCanvasCoordinates(QgsPoint(0.0, 0.0)));
    mSvgRenderer.render(painter, viewBox);
}
}

QRectF TFMapCanvasSvgItem::boundingRect() const
{   
QRectF viewBox = mSvgRenderer.viewBoxF();
qreal halfWeight = viewBox.width() / 2;
qreal halfHeight = viewBox.height() / 2;
return QRectF(-halfWeight, -halfHeight, viewBox.width(), viewBox.height());
}

void TFMapCanvasSvgItem::setFilePath(const QString& file)
{
mFilePath = file;
mSvgRenderer.load(mFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Never mind. I solved the problem.

Comment: Could you please describe how you solved the problem so that others can benefit from your solution?

Comment: @Joseph Ok! Added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must reimplement two functions: paint() and boundingRect().

Here is code:

```
void TFMapCanvasSvgItem::paint(QPainter* painter)
{        
  if (!painter)
  {
    return;
  }
  QImage svgImage(50, 40, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
  QPainter imagePainter(&svgImage);
  mSvgRenderer.render(&imagePainter);
  painter->drawImage(QRect(0, 0, 100, 80), svgImage, QRect(0, 0, 100, 80));
}

QRectF TFMapCanvasSvgItem::boundingRect() const
{   
   QRectF viewBox = mSvgRenderer.viewBoxF();
   qreal halfWeight = viewBox.width() / 2;
   qreal halfHeight = viewBox.height() / 2;
   return QRectF(-halfWeight, -halfHeight, viewBox.width(), viewBox.height());
}
```